# Show Desktops Icon via Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

The easy part is

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path $PathIcon -Name "HideIcons" -Value 1
        Get-Process "explorer" | Stop-Process
```

that does the simple trick of hiding desktop icons but i need a option let them reappear to and for some reason if i do

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path $PathIcon -Name "HideIcons" -Value 0 
        Get-Process "explorer" | Stop-Process
```

that does not let them reappear the Set - Part works fine if i look up the value it is like intended
0 but if i let the explorer force refresh by stoping it and do :

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" -Name HideIcons
```

I can see that the Value is 1 again

Any idears on how to get the icons back ?

Answer (score 0):

I think need somehow forbid to auto restart explorer and after that make stop/start process. Try this one:

```
Set-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" -Name AutoRestartShell -Value 0
Stop-Process -ProcessName "explorer.exe" -Force
Start-Process -FilePath "explorer.exe" -WorkingDirectory "C:\Windows" -Verb Print
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating the NoDesktop key under the given path.

Hide Icons

```
Set-Itemproperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer" -Name NoDesktop -Value 1
Stop-Process -Name explorer
```

Show Icons

```
Set-Itemproperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer" -Name NoDesktop -Value 0
Stop-Process -Name explorer
```

Just in case anybody ever needs that besides me.